# read excel files with Persian characters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file that contains Persian characters and I want to read it by using pandas.
I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('orders_list_1.xlsx', encoding= 'utf-8')
```

but the output is this, instead of Persian characters, there are question marks:

```
 ???? ?????              ...                                      ?????
0       10837              ...                                  ????? ???
1       84486              ...                                  ????? ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass another encoding instead of `utf-8`. Supported Python encodings are listed here: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: Can you please upload a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas itself can easily handle Persian characters. 
I do believe **you should never see the result via windows console**.

Comment: This should be post as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I couldn't find any code for solving this problem in pandas.
I just saved excel as '`CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)`' and I read it as CSV.

```
pd.read_csv("file name")
```

and my problem solved.